# how can I make this submit?

Tags: javascript, forms

Trying to get my form to submit to no avail. Totally new to javascript and HTML so any help would be much appreciated!

```
<form class="form" id="MyForm" onsubmit="submit(get('name').value, get('email').value, get('information').value); return false;">
```

Comment: Without seeing what `submit` and `get` do it's pretty hard to help you.

Comment: Well if you remove the whole onsubmit thing and specifying an action with the correct url it should submit just fine

Comment: Please make sure to add a minimal verifiable code snippet for others to take a look and understand your problem. For more details on how to create [mcve]

Comment: Ok, thanks. Totally new to this site and still trying to work everything out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have an `input` element with `type="submit"` attribute.

If you want to keep the input values while submitting. You could use `"this.[name].value"` as a onsubmit function parameter.

So that, an example form should be like this:

```js
function myFunction(name, email, information) {
  alert("name" + value);
  alert("email" + value);
  alert("information" + value);
}
```

```html
<p>Example form that returns input value as an alert.</p>

<form onsubmit="myFunction(this.name.value, this.email.value, this.information.value)">
  name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
  information: <input type="text" name="information"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
  Enter name: <input id="name" name="name" type="text">
  Enter email: <input id="email" name="email" type="text">
  <!--And more inputs...-->
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

add this code below your form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
  // My Example code (I think you want get input value, True??)
  var Name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var Email = document.getElementById("email").value;

  // Or put your code in here

}
</script>
```

I hope its works, good luck.